# android emulator stops after crash service error

Tags: android, service, crash, emulation, haxm

After uppgrading HAXM to Rev. 6.0.3, emulator had stopped working. After creating Virtual Device, running it gives following Log and stops afterwards

```
 emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
audio: Failed to create voice goldfish_audio'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio output failed
audio: Failed to create voicegoldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

I have added Qt5Core.dll to emulator-crash-device folder, but no luck.

I have tried drag and drop apk file to emulator and its works, but how to view logcat as it does not attach emulator to Android Manager logcat.

Please help.